# No module named coremltools while running in Anaconda Spyder Environment

Tags: python, anaconda, coremltools

The issue looks like this:

```
File "<ipython-input-2-5bf9ddba4efd>", line 1, in <module>
import coremltools

ImportError: No module named coremltools
```

Why?

All I do in python script is

```
import coremltools
```

[image]

As you can see `import coremltools` works fine within terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to restart the terminal and do the following steps again, I faced the same problem and it works for me.

Step 1 - using virtualenv
% sudo pip install virtualenv

Step 2 - set up virtual environment
% virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 python27 <-- this should be the path where you set up virtualenv

Step 3 - activate
% source python27/bin/activate

Step 4 - install the coremltools
pip install -U coremltools

and then you can run the py file in terminal again.

Hope it works for you.